# Filtering on DateTime in Django doesn't work

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have an SQLite database with a *timestamp* column defined as a *DateTime* field. It contains values like *2014-10-14T14:51:07.558*

My Django model has the following field:

```
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(db_column='timestamp', blank=False)
```

Then, when I run the following code, I get an empty set as a result:

```
Model.objects.filter(timestamp=Model.objects.all()[0].timestamp)
```

or

```
edit: removed a 'contains' call
```

Querying

```
Model.objects.all()[0].timestamp
```

returns

```
datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 14, 14, 51, 7, 558000, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Why can't I filter?

Answer (score 0):

Datetimes are not strings; a datetime is a single object,  so it can't 'contain' anything other than itself exactly. According to the django docs though , sqlite doesn't have a native datetime type,  and django uses strings instead,  but in python datetimes are not strings.
The docs aren't clear about what should happen filtering datetime fields using __contains, but it doesn't make much sense to me to do so. If you are trying to check whether a specific datetime falls within a range, use [__range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#range).

That said, you tried a straight = filter, and it didn't have any effect. Try filtering against `str(<datetime>)` since it will be a string in sqlite.

Comment: Well, forget the 'contains' call, shouldn't timestamp=Model.objects.all()[0].timestamp work?

Comment: Yeah sorry, just noticed that. I've updated the answer. I'm on my phone right now, so I can't actual test anything.

Comment: @autonomy: I've tested this against a database I have lying around, but it's using MySQL. Everything works just as expected. So it's probably an SQLite issue. Have you tried doing it using the string representation?

Comment: @autonomy: I've just created a new django app. I'm using django 1.4 and SQLite 3.8.6; And everything works as expected. I do get an error message when creating new entries in the database, complaining `RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2014-10-18 10:05:45.816730) while time zone support is active`; Maybe it's working because I didn't bother about timezones in my test code, but I doubt that. I suspect it's version specific bug with your setup.

Comment: str(datetime) didn't work either. I'm on Django 1.6 and SQLite 3.4.2, I have the same feeling that it's probably a version-specific bug. I ended up just changing all the timestamps to POSIX.